# Various Inputs from Power Automate into Python Script

Tags: python, debugging, input

I am using a power automate desktop flow that calls on a python script and inputs variables from power automate for the script to use. The script then takes the inputs and searches against a database to find the match for the entire row of data. The issue is that there is a total of 4 variables that could be inputted, but the user may input any combination of the 4. For example, they may enter only 2/4 variables, which throws an error because it needs all 4 variables.

```
args = sys.argv[3:]
if args[0] is not None:
    a = args[0]
if args[1] is not None:
    b = args[1]
if args[2] is not None:
    c = args[2]
if args[3] is not None:
    d = args[3]


dict1 = {
    'a': [a],
    'b': [b],
    'c': [c],
    'd': [d]
}
```

I want it to be able to, for example, take arg b and d and use those inputs to complete the script. However, it errors out because it needs all 4 inputs. Is there any way around this without making a bunch of separate scripts for the different possibilities